# php.ini no result (php 5.6, FPM nginx, 1and1 plesk)

Tags: php, nginx, plesk, plesk-onyx

No matter what I do, the changes (max execution_time and max_input_time) to php.ini do not make any difference. Edited the file in command line, then the same file in plesk editor. Reloaded and restarted nginx, finally rebooted the entire server. Still nothing.

Is this the right file to edit? phpinfo says it is at /opt/plesk/php/5.6/etc/php.ini. It there any other file needed to be edited?

Comment: You must to be sure if you are editing the correct php.ini . In index.php or some page write phpinfo(); and look for php path.

Comment: Just run `php --ini |grep php.ini` to find out the path of php.ini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `max execution_time` in your PHP by calling the following command in your terminal:

```
php -r "echo ini_get('max_execution_time').PHP_EOL;"
php -r "echo ini_get('max_input_time').PHP_EOL;"
```

then get your php.ini path by calling the following command and check if you've edited the right one:

```
php --ini |grep “Loaded Configuration File”
```

as you're edited the right php.ini everything should work.

Comment: output:
root@nordoutlet:~# php -r "echo ini_get('max_execution_time').PHP_EOL;"
0
root@domain:~# php -r "echo ini_get('max_input_time').PHP_EOL;"
-1
root@domain:~# ^C
root@domain:~# php --ini |grep “Loaded Configuration File”
grep: Configuration: No such file or directory
grep: File”: No such file or directory

What do the 0 and -1 mean? 0 for no limit?

Comment: max_input_time = -1, which means that max_execution_time is used instead. Set to 0 to allow unlimited time.

Comment: and for `max_execution_time` the value is 0 because you're running php from your command line. As I see there's no php.ini loaded so you were'nt editing anything.